# Exporting Xtext grammar and make a diagram

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext, xbase

i was trying to make a readable file or image for people where show the grammar made in Xtext , i figure out how to export into XML but seem that XML file hasnt got my whole grammar inside . Is there any tool which generates a diagram with the XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Xtext Syntax Graph` view should be helpful for you.

You can open this view in Eclipse by clicking
`Window -> Show view -> Other... -> Xtext -> Xtext Syntax Graph`.
It will show a graphical representation of the Xtext grammar
in the currently selected editor view.

With the save-button the diagram can be exported as a PNG image file.
There is also a [blog post (with video demo)](http://koehnlein.blogspot.de/2011/07/graphical-syntax-view-for-xtext.html) about this feature.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thanks, I wonder is it possible to automate this, i.e. generate an PNG for each xtext file in the project?

Comment: @Metaphox I don't know how to do this. But I recommend you ask a new question about this (may be with reference to the question/answer here).
Probably the Xtext experts have ideas how to achieve it.

Comment: @Metaphox Start by looking into the sources of package
[org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui.graph](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-eclipse/tree/master/org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui.graph/src/org/eclipse/xtext/xtext/ui/graph) and see which parts you could reuse for your purpose.